# Omnetpp model asimmetric channel

Tags: performance, networking, upload, omnet++, asymmetric

I have to model a bittorrent network, so there are a number of node connected each other. Each node has a download speed, say 600KBps, and an upload speed, say 130KBps.
The problem is: how can I model this in omnetpp? in the NED file i created the network this way. If A and B are nodes:

```
A.mygate$o++ --> {something} -->B.mygate$i++
B.mygate$o++ --> {something} -->A.mygate$i++
```

where mygate is a inout gate, $i and $o are the input and output half channel. But something must be a speed, **but**:
if I set a speed to the first line of code, this is the upload speed of A BUT is also the download speed of B. Ths is normal, because if I download from a slow server i have a slow download. How can I model the **download** speed of a peer in Omnetpp? I cannot understand this. Should i have to say: "allow k simultaneus download  untill I reach the download speed?" or it is a bad approach? Can someone suggest me the right approach, and if a modul builtin in omnetpp already exists? I have read the manual but is a bit confusing. Thanks for every reply.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at OverSim which is a peer to peer network simulator on top of INET framework which is the framework to simulate internet related protocols in OMNeT++.

Generally each host should have a queue at link layer and the interfaces that are connected should manage that they do not put out further network packets until the transimmision line is not idle (which is determined by the datarate on the line and the length of the packet). Once the line gets idle, the next packet can be sent out on the line. This is how the datarate is limited by the actual channel.

If you don't want to implement this from scratch (no reason to do that) take a look at the INET framework. You should drop your hosts and connect their PPP interfaces with the asymmetric connection you have proposed in your question. The PPP interface in the StandardHost will do the queueing for you, so you only have to add some applications that generate your traffic, and you are set.

Still I would take a look at OverSim as it gives an even higher level abstraction on top of INET (I have no experience with it though)